# How to sampling the contour's sequence

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, contour

I use opencv sobel filter to find the image's contour.

Now I want to sampling the contour's sequence such like {(0,1),(2,2),(3,4)...}.

I need the algorithm can automatic separate each curve.

Is there any algorithm in opencv or I have to do it by myself?

I only think a simple way that scan the image and record the white point by deep first search but I think it performance isn't good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's wrong with [`findContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#findcontours)?

Given an edge image, the purpose of `findContours` is to give you a two lists of structures, where one list  gives you the pixel coordinates of each contour, and the other list gives a variety of pertinent information that belongs to each detected contour.

In C++, it's as simple as the following.  Assuming your image is stored in a `cv::Mat` structure, you would do something like:

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace cv;

Mat edge_output;  // Declare edge image
// ...
// ...
// Perform sobel detector on image and store in edge_output
// ...
//

// Declare a vector of Points and a vector to store the hierarchy
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

// Find contours
findContours(edge_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
```

`hierarchy` contains information about the image topology.  You can read this page on what the hierarchy means in more detail: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html

However, what you want to focus on is `contours`.  It would be a vector containing vectors of points.  Each element in `contours` would give you a list of `Point` structures that contain the `(x,y)` coordinates of a particular contour. `CV_RETR_TREE` gives you the full information of each contour, and `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` gives you all possible points along the contour.